# Is it OK to ask questions in Stack Overflow which was asked in other forums too?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, etiquette

Is it adequate to ask questions in Stack Overflow (or in any Stack Exchange for that matter) which was asked in other forums too? I use to ask questions here after not getting an answer in other forums for a long time but since Stack Exchange sites have a very active community I wondered if it is acceptable to ask the same question here and in another place without waiting too much.

What do you say?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, IMO absolutely.

If the question is interesting, a good quality one, post.

I would recommend if possible, for honesty's sake to warn with a comment or with a note.

The worst think that could happen is someone not answering your question, if, he got offended!

Answer (score 3):

I recommend asking on a StackExchange site first. If you don't get an answer from that, you can try elsewhere but I think the appropriate StackExchange site for your question should be your first port of call.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow is a very active Community but sometimes happen if you ask your question in Specialty forum you get better answer (it happen to me for some Java Hibernating Question), so if you ask in both forum you have a chance to get better answer.